# Triggering WPF MVVM Button in ContextMenu on Return/Enter

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ContextMenu inside a TreeView, which contains a TextBox and a Button.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ContextOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Create here" IsDefault="True"
                    Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
<TreeView>
```

In terms of mouse operation, this works as expected. Right-click brings up the menu, and the user can then fill in the text box and left-click on the button to execute the AddFolderCommand.

However, the users would also like the button to trigger on pressing Enter/Return, so they can just stick with the keyboard after entering the text.

At the moment, pressing Enter/Return causes the ContextMenu to close, and the focus to switch to the TreeView. But the underlying command does not execute.

I have tried setting `IsDefault="True"` on the button, but its behaviour does not change. There can only be one ContextMenu on the screen open at once. We're using MVVM, so I'd prefer to avoid a code-behind solution if possible. How can I trigger the command on the keypress?

Comment: Your `ViewModel` will not benefit from `KeyPress` in any way, so code-behind would be my initial and final approach, besides the Commands are solely used by the UI so it doesn't matter if it's invoked by the code behind. Don't be afraid, it's going to be alright :-)

Comment: I would also use a KeyPress event, and if its the Enter key, trigger CreateButton.Click event. This kind of View-Specific behavior is perfectly fine to place in the code behind the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ContextOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Create here" IsDefault="True"
                    Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                </Button>
                <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command ="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                </StackPanel.InputBindings>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
<TreeView>
```

This should do the trick without having to even leave the xaml. Note the `<StackPanel.InputBindings>` part